# How to force sbt to redownload dependencies when ivy cache corrupted

Tags: sbt

when ivy cache is corrupted I got the following error from sbt

> [error] unresolved dependency: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.10: configuration not found in commons-codec#commons-codec;
>   1.10: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from com.typesafe.play#play_2.11;2.4.3 compile

if I delete the folder commons-codec in ivy cache and run sbt update, sbt will re-download the dependencies and everything will be fine.

Is there a way to tell sbt to delete the folder and re-download dependencies automatically?

Answer (score 37):

It's pretty easy, just

```
rm -fr ~/.ivy2/cache # Or mv ~/.ivy2/cache ~/.ivy2/cache_bk
sbt update
```

Finally if you are in *Intellij*, File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.

I just did the same thing 20 minutes ago. Probably not a bad thing either. I just saved a pretty big chunk of space on my mac.

```
Atom:~ me$ du -skh ./.iv*
349M    ./.ivy2
1.0G    ./.ivy2_bak
```

[Added  6-May-2021]

If you remove ~/.ivy2 and all your stuff still assembles, cleans, tests, etc. without re-downloading, you might be using another tool, like sdkman, that puts cached files in a different place. Wipe that cache like so.

```
pwd
~/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org
mv ./maven2/ ./_maven2-backup
```

As a word of caution, it is probably best backup your cache files rather than just wiping them. There are cases, like internally developed bad packages, that you might need to copy over from the backup to the new download. Back it up, rebuild your project, then rm -fr the backup.

Comment: I can't do that : this will cause a redownload of all my ivy cache. I don't want to lose time redownloading dependancies that are fine. Especially when I'm on the go with bad connexion.   
And by the way, I want sbt to do it automatically. If I have to go to the ivy cache, I can delete the broken deps by hand.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. I do that a lot too the manual deletions. I don't contribute to SBT either, but I agree it seems like it should be a feature like >sbt clean-dependencies or something instead of just >sbt clean. Good luck Camilo, LMK if you find a better way than working out of ivy cache.

Answer (score 6):

```
  # empty the ivy cache if you have good network
  # rm -rfv ~/.ivy2/cache/*

  # or even better just backup it to sync it later on ...
  # mv ~/.ivy2/cache ~/.ivy2/cache.`date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`.bak


  # remove all sbt lock files
  find ~/.sbt ~/.ivy2 -name "*.lock" -print -delete
  find ~/.sbt ~/.ivy2 -name "ivydata-*.properties" -print -delete


  # remove all the class files
  rm -fvr ~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/target
  rm -fvr ~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/project/target
  rm -fvr ~/.sbt/1.0/target
  rm -fvr ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/target
  rm -fvr ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/project/target
  rm -fvr ~/.sbt/0.13/target
  rm -fvr ./project/target
  rm -fvr ./project/project/target

  sbt clean update
```

Comment: I can't do that : this will cause a redownload of all my ivy cache. I don't want to lose time redownloading dependancies that are fine. Especially when I'm on the go with bad connexion. And by the way, I want sbt to do it automatically. If I have to go to the ivy cache, I can delete the broken deps by hand

Comment: yep, the removal should be done WITH CARE, a better option would be from time to time to actually backup the dir and MERGE it with the new one, because well sbt has it's own flaws ... for me the older versions coursier worked much better, but for sbt 1.0 not anymore ... anyways the reason why I posted this one is the fact , that one must pay attention to those target dirs ... IMO and based on experience a lot of fishy things happen in those dirs , ESPECIALLY if you are the type of guy ( as I am ) to Ctrl+C all the time ...

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the specific dependency that is causing the problem:

```
rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec
```

Comment: This is what I used to do, my question is about an automatic solution with sbt. Not a manual solution I have to maintains

Answer (score 0):

In case someone uses coursier, try this:

```html
rm -rf ~/.cache/coursier
```

and then reload or restart sbt and try it again.